# Android: AAudio linking undefined symbol (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, audio, linker, android-ndk

I've run into an issue with my Flutter app, where the Android version cannot link with the AAudio audio API.

I've tried setting the minimum, target and compile SDK to level 33 (AAudio supports API level 26 at minimum), I've tried various methods to find the library in my CMake script, but to no avail.

Here is the Android part of my CMake script. I've tried finding AAudio, aaudio and libaaudio and they all result in linker errors.

```
# Defining platform build output locations and setting specific platform settings
if(Android)
    find_library(AAudio-lib libaaudio)
    target_link_libraries(PROJECT PRIVATE ${AAudio-lib} android)
    include_directories(${AAudio-lib})
    set(RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Binary/Android)
    add_compile_definitions(ANDROID)
endif()
```

Here is my gradle build settings:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.project"
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
                //path file('../../../../CodeCPP/CMakeLists.txt')
                //version '3.18.1'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('../../../../CodeCPP/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I keep getting this error in the build logs: C/C++: ld: error: undefined symbol: AAudioStreamBuilder_setDirection.

If I comment out that line then I'll get another linker error related to the AAudioStreamBuilder.

The #include <aaudio/AAudio.h> line is included, and the header file can be accessed normally though the IDE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I have found the culprit of my issue: CMake is very finnicky with the Android CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME. Taking the if(Android) out of the equation fixes my linker errors.